# Event on.('event'.... never fired, why?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am doing collaboration task with socket.io, for that I use event.

in my server server.js i have :

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log("socketon");
    socket.on('task', function(task){
        console.log("another task");
        task=ent.encode(task);
        socket.broadcast.emit('task', {task : task});
    })
});
```

and on my view i have shared.ejs I have :

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080/shared/');

socket.on('task', function (data) {
    printtask(data.task);
})

$('#addtask').submit(function () {
    let task = $('#task').val();
    socket.emit('task', task);
    printtask(task);
    $('#task').val('').focus();
    return false;
});

function printtask(task) {
    $('#todolistlist').prepend("<li> <a class='text-danger' href='#'>✘</a>" + task + '</li>');
}
```

Socket is intalled and work fine when i go to the page http://localhost:8080/shared/ i have in console "socketon" however when i click on my submit I haven't  "another task" in console.
I don't know why my event "task" is not fired.
If someone have an idea I would be glad :)
PS: in case of minus please let me know why so that I can upgrade my post
**EDIT:**
here the requirement passed in server.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
let server = require('http').createServer(app);
let ent = require('ent');
var session = require('cookie-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var encodedUrl = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
```

Here the different get (my socket is used in /shared) :

```
.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs');
})
.get('/private/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('todolist.ejs', {todolist: req.session.todolist});
})
.post('/private/add/', encodedUrl, function(req, res) {
    if (req.body.addtodo !=''){
        req.session.todolist.push(req.body.addtodo);
    }
    res.redirect('/private/');
})
.get('/private/delete/:index', function(req, res) {
    if (req.param.index != '') {
        req.session.todolist.splice(req.params.index, 1);
    }
    res.redirect('/private/');
})
.get('/shared/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('shared.ejs');
  })
.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.redirect('/')
});
```

here the html content of my shared.ejs

```html
<div class='container'>
                <div class= row>
                    <ul id="todolistlist" class="offset-lg-2 col-lg-8 list-group list-group-flush">
                    </ul>
                    <section class="offset-lg-1 col-lg-1">
                        <p>connected:</p>    
                        <ul id="todolistmembers" class="list-group list-group-flush">
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                </div>
                <form id='addtask' method='post' class="form-inline offset-lg-2 mb-3 col-lg-8 align-items-center">
                    <div class="input-group w-100" >
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <label id="basic-addon3" class="input-group-text" for="addtodo">What to do ?</label>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" id="task" class="form-control" style="text-align:right" name="addtodo" id="addtodo" autofocus />
                        <span class="input-group-append">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="add"/>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
            <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure the "submit" handler is called ?

Comment: yes, the area text is added from the jQuery, it's strange it's like if the event didn't exist but it is (but a point is that I use it on a page of my app)

Comment: Why are you connecting to `'http://localhost:8080/shared/'` instead of `'http://localhost:8080'`?  You are connecting to a socket.io namespace named `shared` so your events are going to be shown on the server only to that namespace.  So, unless you register your event handlers on the server in that namespace, you won't see the events.

Comment: @jfriend00 it was that thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connecting to 'http://localhost:8080/shared/' instead of 'http://localhost:8080' is connecting to a specific socket.io namespace named `shared`.  So your events are going to be shown on the server only to that namespace. So, unless you register your event handlers on the server in that namespace or remove the `/shared` from the connection URL, you won't see the events.